# Python Json Output From AWS Not Removing Single Quotes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, replace, boto3

I am kind of new to Python and playing around with classes. I created a class to access aws ec2 instances to stop and start along with current state. Don't know how else to explain this other than showing the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import json
import datetime
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

class Ec2(object):
    def __init__(self, instance_id, region):
        self.instances = [instance_id]
        self.region = 'us-gov-west-1'
        self.state = ''

        if region is not None:
            self.region = region
        self.ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
        self._setState()

    def _setState(self):
        def convert_timestamp(datetime_key):
            if isinstance(datetime_key, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
                return datetime_key.timestamp()

        status = self.ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=self.instances)

        # Find the current status of the instance
        dump = json.dumps(status, default=convert_timestamp)
        body = json.loads(dump)
        self.state = body["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["State"]["Name"]


    def getState(self):
        self._setState()
        return self.state
    ...
```

So if in the Python3 interpretor I run this:

```
from ec2 import Ec2
ssm_1 = Ec2('i-12345abcdef','us-gov-west-1')
ssm_1.getState()
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ec2 import Ec2
>>> ssm_1 = Ec2('i-12345abcdef','us-gov-west-1')
>>> ssm_1.getState()
'stopped'
>>>
```

If I change the method _setState in the class to:

```
def _setState(self):
        def convert_timestamp(datetime_key):
            if isinstance(datetime_key, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
                return datetime_key.timestamp()

        status = self.ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=self.instances)

        # Find the current status of the instance
        dump = json.dumps(status, default=convert_timestamp)
        body = json.loads(dump)
        self.state = body["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["State"]["Name"]
        self.state = self.state.replace("'", "")
```

then rerun above the single quotes do not get removed! It appears that these quotes are not part of the actual string, validated by changing the last line to:

```
        self.state = self.state[1:-1]

>>> ssm_1.getState()
'toppe'
```

so it removed the first and last letters not the single quotes, s & d

BUT if I change _setState to:

```
    def _setState(self):
        def convert_timestamp(datetime_key):
            if isinstance(datetime_key, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
                return datetime_key.timestamp()

        status = self.ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=self.instances)

        # Find the current status of the instance
        dump = json.dumps(status, default=convert_timestamp)
        body = json.loads(dump)
        self.state = body["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["State"]["Name"]
```

Now run:

```
>>> from ec2 import Ec2
>>> ssm_1 = Ec2('i-12345abcdef','us-gov-west-1')
>>> ssm_1.getState().replace("'", "")
stopped
>>>
```

the single quotes are now gone!

So it appears in the class the string does not actually include the single quotes but outside the class it does. Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can you infer from the value of `len(ssm_1.getState())`?

Comment: It's kind of a weird question. The quotes are just the way Python displays strings. If your string would actually have a quote as part of it, it would be displayed as "'stopped'" instead.

Comment: jarmod:     >>> len(ssm_1.getState())
returns: 7 which I would expect since that is the length of the word stopped

Comment: Right, because there are no quotes in the string and hence there's no need to attempt to remove quotes (there are none). The fact that you're seeing quotes when that string is printed is an artifact of Python or the REPL.

Comment: Back to original question then if it is an "artifact" of python, why am I able to remove single quotes outside class but not inside class? Outside the class to check for a stopped state you have to include single quotes in the sting comparison because 'stopped' is returned not stopped.